# Upgrading from Tastypie 0.9.11 to 0.11 obj_get_list

Tags: python, django, tastypie

Code that worked in api.py
With Python 2.6, Django 1.4.1, Tastypie 0.9.11 (Running on 2.6.32-48-generic-pae #110-Ubuntu SMP)

```
class DriveResource(CommonModelResource):
    driver = fields.ForeignKey(DriverResource, 'driver')
    bus = fields.ForeignKey(BusResource, 'bus')
    route = fields.ForeignKey(RouteResource, 'route')

    class Meta(CommonModelResource.Meta):
        queryset = Drive.objects.all()
        allowed_methods = ['get', 'put']
        excludes = ('bus_location',)
        filtering = {
            'updated': ('gt', 'gte', 'lt', 'lte', 'exact'),
            'id': ('exact',),
        }

    def get_object_list(self, request):
        whole_list = super(DriveResource, self).get_object_list(request)
        todays_day_name = datetime.now().strftime('%w')
        filtered_list = whole_list.filter(driver__user=request.user).filter(day=todays_day_name)
        return filtered_list

    def dehydrate_driver(self, bundle):
        return bundle.obj.driver.person_id

    def dehydrate_bus(self, bundle):
        return bundle.obj.bus.number

    def dehydrate_route(self, bundle):
        return bundle.obj.route.id

    def hydrate_bus_location(self, bundle):
        # Guard against the method being called twice
        if not hasattr(bundle, 'geopoint_processed'):
            lon = bundle.data['bus_location'][0] / 1e6
            lat = bundle.data['bus_location'][1] / 1e6
            bundle.data['bus_location'] = Point(lon, lat)
            bundle.geopoint_processed = True
        return bundle


class DriveFullResource(CommonModelResource):
    driver = fields.ForeignKey(DriverResource, 'driver', full=True, blank=True, null=True)
    bus = fields.ForeignKey(BusResource, 'bus', full=True, blank=True, null=True)
    route = fields.ForeignKey(RouteResource, 'route', full=True)

    class Meta(CommonModelResource.Meta):
        queryset = Drive.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'drive'
        allowed_methods = ['get', 'put']
        excludes = ('bus_location',)

    def obj_get_list(self, request=None, **kwargs):
        whole_list = super(DriveFullResource, self).obj_get_list(request, **kwargs)
        todays_day_name = datetime.now().strftime('%w')
        filtered_list = whole_list.filter(driver__user=request.user).filter(day=todays_day_name)
        return filtered_list

    def hydrate_bus_location(self, bundle):
        # Guard against the method being called twice
        if not hasattr(bundle, 'geopoint_processed'):
            lon = bundle.data['bus_location'][0] / 1e6
            lat = bundle.data['bus_location'][1] / 1e6
            bundle.data['bus_location'] = Point(lon, lat)
            bundle.geopoint_processed = True
        return bundle

    def put_detail(self, request, **kwargs):
        deserialized = self.deserialize(request, request.raw_post_data, format=request.META.get('CONTENT_TYPE', 'application/json'))
        deserialized = self.alter_deserialized_detail_data(request, deserialized)
        bundle = self.build_bundle(data=dict_strip_unicode_keys(deserialized), request=request)

        try:
            drive = Drive.objects.get(pk=kwargs['pk'])
            bundle = self.hydrate_bus_location(bundle)
            drive.bus_location = bundle.data['bus_location']
            drive.save()
            return http.HttpNoContent()
        except:
            return http.HttpBadRequest()
```

Does not work with
Python 2.6, Django 1.5,  Tastypie 0.11 (Running on Centos 5)

Calling server with : https://api.server.com/api/full/drive/?format=json&limit=50&user=12345

I tried changing to:

```
def obj_get_list(self, bundle, **kwargs):
    request = bundle.request
    whole_list = super(DriveFullResource, self).get_object_list(request)
    todays_day_name = datetime.now().strftime('%w')
    filtered_list = whole_list.filter(driver__user=request.user).filter(day=todays_day_name)
    return filtered_list
```

and

```
def obj_get_list(self, bundle, **kwargs):
    request = bundle.request
    whole_list = super(DriveFullResource, self).obj_get_list(bundle, **kwargs)
    todays_day_name = datetime.now().strftime('%w')
    filtered_list = whole_list.filter(driver__user=request.user).filter(day=todays_day_name)
    return filtered_list
```

Still get error messages of the type below:

```
{"error_message": "obj_get_list() got multiple values for keyword
argument 'bundle'", "traceback": "Traceback (most recent call
last):\n\n  File
\"/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 195,
in wrapper\n\n  File
\"/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 426,
in dispatch_list\n\n  File
\"/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 458,
in dispatch\n\n  File
\"/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 1266,
in get_list\n\n  File
\"/home/django_projects/project/src/routes/api.py\", line 110, in
obj_get_list\n    request = bundle.request\n\nTypeError:
obj_get_list() got multiple values for keyword argument 'bundle'\n"}

{"error_message": "obj_get_list() got multiple values for keyword
argument 'bundle'", "traceback": "Traceback (most recent call
last):\n\n  File
\"/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 195,
in wrapper\n\n  File
\"/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 426,
in dispatch_list\n\n  File
\"/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 458,
in dispatch\n\n  File
\"/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 1266,
in get_list\n\n  File
\"/home/django_projects/project/src/routes/api.py\", line 114, in
obj_get_list\n    return filtered_list\n\nTypeError: obj_get_list()
got multiple values for keyword argument 'bundle'\n"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested the method on Tastypie 0.11 and seems to work ok. But in my opinion you are taking wrong and error prone approach. I prepared solution that will eliminate them.

**Problem definition**
You didn't defined what is your code supposed to do. Reviewing code I assume you want to have resource that returns object for currently logged user and filtered by day name.
In other words you want to limit access to resource - And this is.. I think you know, authorization.

**Why not obj_get_list?**
You see that Tastypie `obj_get_list` is quite Django ORM specific and not documented well. I don't really know how to use it. I wouldn't dare to deal with it.

**Solution**
Let's define Authorization class for your resource:

```
from datetime import datetime

from tastypie.authorization import Authorization


class DriverAuthorization(Authorization):
    def read_list(self, object_list, bundle):
        todays_day_name = datetime.now().strftime('%w')
        return object_list.filter(driver__user=bundle.request.user,
                                  day=todays_day_name)

    def read_detail(self, object_list, bundle):
        todays_day_name = datetime.now().strftime('%w')
        return bundle.obj.day == todays_day_name and bundle.obj.driver.user == bundle.request.user

    def create_list(self, object_list, bundle):
        return []

    def create_detail(self, object_list, bundle):
        return False

    def update_list(self, object_list, bundle):
        return []

    def update_detail(self, object_list, bundle):
        object_before_update = object_list.get(pk=bundle.obj.pk)
        return object_before_update.driver.user == bundle.request.user

    def delete_list(self, object_list, bundle):
        return []

    def delete_detail(self, object_list, bundle):
        return False
```

Now attach authorization to resource:

```
class DriveResource(CommonModelResource):
    driver = fields.ForeignKey(DriverResource, 'driver')
    bus = fields.ForeignKey(BusResource, 'bus')
    route = fields.ForeignKey(RouteResource, 'route')

    class Meta(CommonModelResource.Meta):
        queryset = Drive.objects.all()
        allowed_methods = ['get', 'put']
        excludes = ('bus_location',)
        authorization = DriverAuthorization()
        filtering = {
            'updated': ('gt', 'gte', 'lt', 'lte', 'exact'),
            'id': ('exact',),
        }

    def dehydrate_driver(self, bundle):
        return bundle.obj.driver.person_id

    def dehydrate_bus(self, bundle):
        return bundle.obj.bus.number

    def dehydrate_route(self, bundle):
        return bundle.obj.route.id

    def hydrate_bus_location(self, bundle):
        # Guard against the method being called twice
        if not hasattr(bundle, 'geopoint_processed'):
            lon = bundle.data['bus_location'][0] / 1e6
            lat = bundle.data['bus_location'][1] / 1e6
            bundle.data['bus_location'] = Point(lon, lat)
            bundle.geopoint_processed = True
        return bundle
```

**Benefits**
1. Code now is much more clearer to read
2. You have control on what user can do or cannot do in one place.
3. No `obj_get_list` means no more problems.